# Resolve and Troubleshoot Azure web App 500 Internal Server Error Timeout Issue

Tags: azure, web-applications, server, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

We have an web api hosted on Azure Web APp. We are getting intermittently 500 Internal Server Error Timeout Issue. We have appinsights in place which is used for Exception Logging but nothing is getting logged for this issue. How we can troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue might caused due to these reasons:

1.Due to Network problem of your server

2.Due to server request time out

a.I think you can once use Await/Abort in your code for asynchronous the request purpose,
                     or

b.Increase the request time of your browser